# Trouble getting a file descriptor from pyhandle

Tags: python, winapi, twisted

I want to use a twisted callback with a TUN interface that I've opened in Windows using Python.  I am getting a PyHandle using win32file.CreateFile().  In order to use Twisted, I (think I) have to use a file descriptor. So I am trying to convert to an fd by doing this:

```
self.tunfd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(self.tun_handle, 0)
```

Using zero as the second parameter is what's shown in many examples I've seen on the web while troubleshooting, and experimenting with the applicable flags has not resolved the issue.  In each case I get this error:

```
self.tunfd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(self.tun_handle, 0)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Why wouldn't this work?  And is there an easier way to use Twisted with PyHandle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File descriptors on Windows are a trick.  I don't know whether there's some way to get a file descriptor for a TUN device on Windows but even if you manage to get one somehow, it won't work with Twisted.  On Windows, Twisted is limited to interacting with file descriptors that represent sockets.  This has to do with the way the Windows APIs that accept file descriptors work.

You have two options.  You can use [`IReactorWin32Events`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorWin32Events.html) to monitor a Windows `Event` and then use some other Windows API to trigger the event when something interesting happens to `tun_handle`.  Or perhaps you can use [`IOCPReactor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.iocpreactor.reactor.IOCPReactor.html) to monitor the handle for interesting activity directly (unfortunately the `IOCPReactor` APIs for this are not as well documented - but I think `registerHandle` is probably the main thing).